# "pointAttr" attribute is missing in Highcharts library 5.0.0

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

The fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n3e49ws2/1/ uses highcharts library v4.2.7. In this fiddle, on selecting any data point, it is observed that "pointAttr" attribute exists on "this" for the select event handler.

```
point: {
    events: {
        select: function() {
          if (this.pointAttr)
            alert("pointAttr exists.");
          else
            alert("pointAttr does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n3e49ws2/ uses latest highcharts library 5.0.0. In this, i am not able to get the "pointAttr" attribute on "this" for select event handler. Why was this change made? Is there any alternative for the "pointAttr" attribute since I want to change the SVG point directly.

Comment: `console.log(this)` and see what you do have access to. Then go from there...  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/n3e49ws2/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get pointAttr, use `this.series.pointAttribs(this, state);` where `state` can be one of `""`, `"hover"` or `"select"`.